# Toggle Div Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have a form that contains field sets and has the ability to add a new section (clone of a previous field set). I can toggle between the original field sets fine but when I add a new section only the originals work. I believe that there may be an issue with the fact that the new section is nestled within a div.

My code and example are listed here -> http://jsbin.com/aqijuh

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that if you click the headers many times quickly that the animations play out one after another. To stop this you can use the jQuery function `.stop()`: http://api.jquery.com/stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `on` because you are adding the elements dynamically. If you using jQuery < 1.7 then you should use `delegate`. Try this

Using `on`

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="button"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('legend').next('div').toggle('slow');
});
```

Using `delegate`

```
$(document).delegate('click', '[id^="button"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('legend').next('div').toggle('slow');
});
```